# How do I install BuildTools 17 and Up in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, build-tools

Android Studio only gives me an option to install Android SDK Build-Tools 26, how do I install for BuildTools 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SDK Manager, go to **SDK Tools** tab, click on **Show Package Details** on the bottom of SDK Manager window. Scroll down and check the versions you want to download.